# MySQL-select 10 rows with limit on categories column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table in my database which has 3 columns: `(id, business_id, name)`. I need to write a query which selects 10 rows from table which have `id` greater than a specific value **and the point is that not more than 5 rows must be selected for each business_id**. how to include this criteria in the query?

so for example if we have these rows in table:

```
1   A   JAD
2   A   LPO
3   A   LMN
4   A   ABC
5   A   QWE
6   A   WER
7   B   TYU
8   B   POI
9   B   AQZ
10  B   UYT
11  C   CDE
12  C   XYZ
```

the desired result is (for `id`>0):

```
1   A   JAD
2   A   LPO
3   A   LMN
4   A   ABC
5   A   QWE
7   B   TYU
8   B   POI
9   B   AQZ
10  B   UYT
11  C   CDE
```

Comment: [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61266438/edit) with your attempted query and expected output.

Comment: and include the mysql version

Comment: @danblack 5.7.26

Comment: Look at [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+enumerate+records+using+variables) and select any answer. Enumerate your records in groups separately (with filtering by ID) in subquery. Then, in outer query, select records with filtering by the number in the group (<=5) and total records amount limitation.

Comment: PS. Does your query must be deterministic?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY business_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, business_id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: many thanks. but unfortunately the current MySQL version is 5.7.26

Comment: to simulate row number in MySQL 5.7 uses session variables

Comment: @AbinashGhosh `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition is actually pretty tricky to pull off in MySQL 5.7.  My attitude in 2020 is that if someone has a persistent need for this, just upgrade to 8+.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it better to upgrade to 8+ but I just to give him an option if upgrade is not possible for him.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where id > @id and
      id < any (select t2.id
                from t t2
                where t2.business_id = t.business_id
                order by id asc
                limit 1 offset 4
               )
limit 10;
```

The `any` is to handle the case where a business has fewer than four rows.